# How can I resolve socket closed exception with messages queued on the channel

Tags: mirth

I have a channel which is in stopped state right and big message queue. I can't start it.

If I try to start it says
Error receiving message (TCP Listener "Source" on channel 030d63a3-750a-47987-ac4c-92b95546b8bf).
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Failed to create server socket (TCP Listener "Source" on channel a322164c-a1da-4b8e

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means that you already have one channel listening on the port you tried to use, and you can’t do that.

To see which ports are currently in use, you can just open CMD if your using Windows and type “netstat-a”.

You can also try exporting a Mirth config backup, and open in Excel.  There is a column labeled "port"(usually column AN2 or somewhere nearby) and you can easily find which channel you are causing the duplication.